# Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1)

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, annotate

I am trying to mix annotate and expression statements in ggplot2.  I'm getting a consistent error "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1)". My first thought was that I had the wrong number of variables in aes.  That might still be true, but I couldn't wrap my head around fixing it.  So I searched and found errors and solutions that didn't seem to address the underlying problem. Here's my code:

```
r2.val <- .09
pl <- qplot(c(0,30))
pl+annotate(geom="text",x=0,y=28,label=(bquote(Value~is~sigma~R^{2}==.
(r2.val))))
```

Comment: Something like this `pl+annotate(geom="text",x=0,y=28,label=paste0("Value~is~Sigma~R^{2}==", r2.val), parse=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `bquote` but it looks like you can achieve what you're trying to do by using `paste0` and setting `parse = TRUE` in `annotate`:

```
pl + annotate(geom="text", x=10, y=1, 
              label = paste0("Value~is~sigma~R^2==", r2.val), parse = TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you. I may use your suggestion.  The post where I found the bquote function also mentioned that using paste or paste0 might be possible, but should be discouraged.  Obviously, I don't understand bquote either, but if I leave the question open I might learn more.

Answer (score -1):

```
pl <- qplot(c(0,30))
r2.val = 0.42
pl+annotate(geom="text",x=8,y=-.2,label=(paste("Value~is~sigma~R^{2}==",
                                               (r2.val))))
```

?

Comment: Thank you, that corrects the missing value for r2.val, but I continue to see the Aesthetics error message.  In my main session, that is the only error message I see.  In a different, fresh session I also get "`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`."

Comment: @SteveM49 That's just letting you know that it's using the default number of bins with 30 for the histogram. If you want to change that add `binwidth = <width of bins>` inside `qplot`.