# How to plot line segments in ggplot2 when aesthetics do not have length 1 or same length as the data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I' m trying to plot line segments with ggplot2 in order to make an example of a Miniminum Spanning Tree (MST).

I'm able to do that with base R but I' m having problems when trying to enhance my plot with ggplot2.

I have the following example:

**w/ base R**

```
# simulating data
n=10
set.seed(1984)
d1<-matrix(rnorm(n,mean=2,sd=1), n/2, 2)
d2<-matrix(rnorm(n,mean=-2,sd=.5), n/2, 2)
d<-rbind(d1,d2)

# starting and ending points
from<-c(1,1,2,2,4,6,7,7,10)
to<-c(5,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,8)

# plot
plot(d[,1:2])
segments(d[from,1], d[from,2], d[to,1], d[to,2],col="blue")
```

[image]

**w/ ggplot2**

```
df<-as.data.frame(d)
library(ggplot2)
b <- ggplot(df, aes(df[,1], df[,2])) + geom_point()
b + geom_segment(aes(x = df[from,1], y = df[from,2],
               xend = df[to,1], yend = df[to,2]), colour="red", data = df)
```

**Edit**: substituted colour="segment" by colour="red", since colour= "segment" does not make sense in this example.

As you may notice, I've used the same logic from segments() function from base R, but ggplot complains about the length of my aesthetics, since it will be the length of data -1.

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): x, y, xend, yend, colour

In http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html the logic seems to be valid but I still don't have any clue on how to handle the aesthetics length problem.

I've read other related questions in Stack Overflow but I was not able to find a solution to my problem since my aesthetics will not have the same length of my data.

Related questions:

[Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (207): x, y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207090/aesthetics-must-be-either-length-1-or-the-same-as-the-data-207-x-y)

[Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): x, y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776133/error-aesthetics-must-be-either-length-1-or-the-same-as-the-data-10-x-y)

[Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551846/aesthetics-must-be-either-length-1-or-the-same-as-the-data-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. `from` and `to` contained 9 elements, your data ten. I added a (useless) tenth element to `from` and `to`. Then your code works fine.

```
from <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 7, 10, 10)
to <- c(5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8, 10)

b <- ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point()
b + geom_segment(aes(
 x = df[from, 1],
 y = df[from, 2],
 xend = df[to, 1],
 yend = df[to, 2],
 colour = "segment"
), data = df)
```

Which gives the following plot

[image]

Sidenote: why `colour = "segment"`?

Comment: Thank you! Nice trick!! colour="segment" comes from Hadley's example at http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html. But here it is not relevant, as you have pointed out. I will edit my question in order to make it more clear to other users. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. By the way, if you want to assign a single colour to all segments, put the colour argument outside of `aes()`.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. I've fixed the code in the example. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider to construct a separate data frame for the segments:

```
dfseg <- data.frame(V1=df[from,1], V2=df[from,2], xend=df[to,1], yend=df[to,2])
ggplot(df, aes(V1,V2)) + geom_point() + geom_segment(data=dfseg, aes(xend=xend, yend=yend))
```

Comment: Indeed, it is a neat solution. Thank you!